# Access is denied errors starting ADUC on non-domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have a primary domain controller running Server 2012 R2. It is running just fine. I have a secondary server running Server 2008 R2 Datacenter. The 2008 R2 server is not a domain controller. The Remote Server Administration Tools have been installed because I want to be able to use Active Directory Users & Computers from this server.

Every time I launch ADUC, I get an error:

"Naming information cannot be located because: Access is denied"

Every time I launch AD Domains & Trusts, I get an error:

"The configuration information describing this enterprise is not available"

I have checked IPv4 settings between the two servers and they match. I am also a member of the domain administrators group which does have local admin on the server.

I am wondering what kind of cause could this 'access denied' be coming from? I just can't get it to see the domain controller...

Thanks for your help!

Edit, ipconfig /all output:

```
Domain Controller:

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : mydc01
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mydomain.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mydomain.com
                                       my-dc.c3.internal.cloudapp.net

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : my-dc.c3.internal.cloudapp.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0E-3B-00-61-1E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::888f:ae4c:8194:33c6%16(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.183.209.132(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, October 1, 2015 10:08:09 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 3, 2151 12:56:30 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.183.209.129
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.63.129.16
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369102138
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-D3-FC-0D-00-0D-3A-00-21-1F

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.183.209.132
                                       10.183.209.133
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Secondary Server:


Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : my-util01
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mydomain.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mydomain.com
                                       my-util01.c3.internal.cloudapp.net

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 28:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : my-util01.c3.internal.cloudapp.net
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Ada
pter #28
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0E-5F-00-3E-F6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cdec:c904:e5a7:102c%42(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.183.209.134(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, October 26, 2015 6:21:50 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 03, 2151 1:00:22 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.183.209.129
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.63.129.16
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 754978106
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-17-3D-0F-00-15-5D-05-4B-22

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.183.209.132
                                       10.183.209.133
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: I also have to mention, I am unable to force updates of Group Policy on the 2008 R2 server. Every time I try to do a gpupdate /force, I get the below:

`The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \\mydomain.com\sysvol\mydomain.com\Policies\{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved`...etc etc etc

Comment: What are the DC and the server in question using for DNS?

Comment: @joeqwerty If I do ipconfig /all on the DC and on the server, they are both showing the same IP addresses. The DNS suffix for each one lists the domain first, and the second suffix says something different for each one, if that matters.

Also, if I just straight copy and paste that UNC path, it does not work. If I replace the initial \\mydomain.com with the server name of the DC \\mydc01\etc etc.., it is a valid path.

Comment: I'm asking specifically what they're using, not whether or not they're the same. What is each of them using for DNS? The DC? The ISP? What? Why do they have more than one DNS suffix? Are you setting a per-connection DNS suffix on them? Please post the output of ipconfig/all from each one of them in your question.

Comment: @Michael: What is the output of `nltest /dsgetdc:mydomain.com`

Comment: I posted my ipconfig /all output, I tried to make it cleaner..

Comment: @GregAskew Here is the output:

           DC: \\my-dc02.mydomain.com
      Address: \\10.183.209.133
     Dom Guid: 33e289e9-408f-4935-b664-f747e957f083
     Dom Name: mydomain.com
  Forest Name: mydomain.com
 Dc Site Name: Prod-East2
Our Site Name: Prod-East2
        Flags: GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLO
SE_SITE FULL_SECRET 0xC000
The command completed successfully

Comment: @joeqwerty The two DNS servers are the IP's of the DC I mentioned above, and a secondary DC that I did not mention (my-dc02)

Comment: You also didn't mention that these are Azure virtual machines. It would have been good to include **all** of the relevant details in your question.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, they are. Sorry for that missing detail.

Comment: @Michael: so the 2008 R2 server is using 10.183.209.133 for the domain controller.  Can you run PortQueryUI on the 2008 R2 server against 10.183.209.133.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27661.portqueryui-gui-tool-that-can-be-used-for-troubleshooting-port-connectivity-issues.aspx (Select "Domains and Trusts").

Comment: As a start, each DC should use it's partner DC for primary DNS, itself for secondary DNS and 127.0.0.1 for tertiary DNS. Make those changes and then reboot each DC in turn. Then run the nltest command Greg mentioned from the member server and post the results here. Also, confirm that you have fundamental network connectivity between these virtual machines.

Comment: @joeqwerty But since the my-util01 server is not a domain controller, should I still set itself for secondary DNS?? This is a strange issue, because another person is able to RDP in and open ADUC without issues, but this problem is happening on another account and any new accounts.

Comment: I am not so sure about rebooting the dc1, since its a production DC ;/

Comment: @joeqwerty I doubt this is a DNS issue. Another user is able to remotely connect and open ADUC just fine. Two other accounts (one being mine, and brand new) is experiencing the issue.

Comment: I didn't say to configure the domain member to use itself for DNS. I clearly stated how the DC servers should be configured for DNS. Each **DC** should use it's partner **DC** for primary DNS, itself for secondary DNS and 127.0.0.1 for tertiary DNS. You can configure the DNS settings on the member server anyway you like, just as long as it's only using the two DC's for DNS. The order doesn't really matter on the member server.

Comment: @joeqwerty Something strange I noticed...from the problematic server, I cannot access the SYSVOL share.....any other machine I log into can access it though...

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may be related to the fact that your connection-specific suffix is different from your AD domain name. Do you have to keep that name? Can you change your connection-specific name to be your AD domain name only?

Comment: These are Azure VM's

Comment: And you didn't think that was worth mentioning?